# Marquee loop not infinite

Tags: javascript, html

I have a marquee in a game that i would like to repeat once finished.

```
var elems = "<br />";
elems += "<marquee id='m1' direction='left' width='800' scrolldelay='5' scrollspeed='true' scrollamount='2'  loop='infinite' >";
        if (exp >= 0) {
            elems += "Galactic News:" + arr0[exp] + "";
        }
        if (lfLvl >= 0) {

            elems += "Planet News: " + arr1[lfLvl] + "";
        }
        elems += "</marquee>";
```

when I run app, the variable goes to a part of the page where i want the marquee.  It plays through fine.  But once it's over, it's does not begin again. It will start again if the user navigates away and comes back.

I would like to know some reason why it isn't repeating, as well as a solution.  If i can't do it, i'm not too bothered. It's just a polishing issue that i would like to get out of the way.  Thank you to anyone that can help.

Another alternate solution i was thinking of, was to detect when the last item runs, and the marquee has finished, then to throw in a last thing saying something like "end of feed" or something like:

```
if (marquee === over) {
    elems += "End of Feed";
}
```

but i don't know exactly how to do that over variable, so i kinda had my fingers crossed with attribute

```
loop='infinite'
```

Comment: Just incase anyone is not already aware of this, the `marquee` element is obsolete and browsers may not support this element. You can still accomplish this without the `marquee` element by using JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, but this is not for any browser.  This game will be released on windows store for win10 and win10 mobile.  does that matter?

Comment: Yes. It's depreciated in HTML, not in particular application. It might work at the moment, but support can be dropped at any time, and I'm expecting sooner rather than later.

Comment: Also, because it's depreciated, some of its features, such as infinite loop, may not supported even if marquee itself is supported.

Comment: thanks for the info, i will look up a few alternatives to the marquee to use in JS.   That way i have something that i know will work, always

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing your loop to `-1` like this:

```
<marquee id='m1' direction='left' width='800' scrolldelay='5' scrollspeed='true' scrollamount='2'  loop='-1' >
```

Comment: this did the trick, i had no idea that i could do the loop like that.  Although, this is the first(and probably last) time i've ever used the marquee element.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try avoid the marquee element, it's outdated. Use jquery and css animations instead!

Comment: I try to avoid jquery, i don't really have an excuse.  I just don't like attaching bulky libraries only to use a few of it's resources.  I like writing my codes in "vanilla".  That way, my apps can still work without internet connections